# GUI changes with RadioButton Selection

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, jtextfield, jradiobutton

Per the title, I'm trying to get my GUI change with RadioButton selection. More specifically, the JLabels and JTextfields. Essentially, I want to look something like this: http://i40.tinypic.com/262sec7.png, where the first three labels and fields are always the same, and the last two fields and labels are different.

I know it needs to occur via the ActionListeners for the RadioButtons. Should everything from the Labels down be created in the ActionListeners? Then cleared and created again based on the RadioButton selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

[CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) is a [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) which allows you add multiple components and choose which one is shown using `CardLayout.show(Container parent, String name)`. Only one component at a time will be visible.

There's a tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

In your case, you would add a different `JPanel` with all the controls you want for each radio button. Then, the radio button `ActionListener` would simply call `CardLayout.show( ... )` to show the appropriate set of controls.

Comment: In @user1349999's situation, most of the GUI would remain unchanged, including the JRadioButtons at the top and the JButtons at the bottom, but the central JPanel would use CardLayout and would hold and display the grid of JTextFields and JLabels. 1+ for your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. CardLayout really helped.